# Django - testing pages for 500 status

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, internal-server-error

I've got a project where some changes may lead to 500 status in some views.

What is the most elegant way to make unit tests that will check *all* the views/pages (with static routes, without vars in them, of course) for not returning 500 status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unit tests you can use something like:

```
from django import test
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from page.urls import urlpatterns

class PageTest(test.TestCase):

   def test_responses(self):
       for url in urlpatterns:
           response = self.client.get(reverse(url.name))
           self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: That won't work for pages with parameters, i believe. But to ignore them, i can check for NoReverseMatch exception.